# Why does JMH @Measurement (and @Warmup) specify a fixed time rather than a fixed number of operations?

Tags: jmh

I have seen this discussed as one of the potential pitfalls in microbenchmarking. If you specify that @Measurement (or @Warmup) will run for a fixed amount of time, it means that, when comparing different runs (e.g., different platforms, different versions of the VM, etc.), you will get less of an "apples to apples" comparison because the runs will not be doing the same work!

If one run executes faster, then it will go through more operations in a given time. This introduces confounding factors that may skew your results: more opportunities for dynamic optimization, differences in caching, different statistics per operation, etc.

On the other hand, if you specify a fixed number of operations, then each run is doing exactly the same quantity of work, which improves confidence in the results.

So, what is the reason that JMH utilizes this method of specifying a fixed amount of time rather than a fixed number of operations? Is there some important reason driving this design decision that I am missing? I have searched both within the JMH documentation and in online discussions, but I have not been able to find an answer to this question.

Answer (score 4):

A fixed number is likely to be a poor choice. Let's say we choose 10,000 which is just enough to warm up the code. If the operation is very short, this might not be enough to get the best result but if it takes say 10 seconds, 10 runs will take 12 days to get a result. Running for a fixed time you at least know how long it will take.

In real world usage, you are likely to run the code for a known amount of time rather than a fixed number of iterations.